# Error when trying to change imaginary unit's style

Tags: math-mode, fonts, macros

I want to have a special symbol for the imaginary unit `i`, but I also need the usual character for the letter `i` in the same context. So, I tried to change the style of the imaginary unit by setting

```
\def \i{\begingroup\mathgroup=0 i\endgroup}
```

This is supposed to return a different symbol for `i` when typing `\i` in math-mode, but it refuses to do so! I get the error message:

*Command \i invalid in math mode*

Why is that and what can I do to obtain a different `i` for my complex numbers?

Comment: Don't use one-letter command names, use longer names.

Comment: It is a bad idea to use `\i` which has a pre-existing meaning, use any other name, (`\newcommand` rather than `def` would have warned you of that)

Comment: What's wrong with `\imath`?

Comment: why use all these low level commands `\def`, `\mathgroup`, `\begingroup` etc. It seems you want `\newcommand\imagi{\mathrm{i}}` then use `\imagi`

Comment: I am new to Latex and I wasn't aware neither of `\mathrm{•}` nor `\imath`. However, what is `\i` supposed to do normally? @David
By the way, thank you very much for your replies.

Comment: `\i` is the command for getting the “dotless i”. It's best not to redefine it.

Comment: If you are new where did you learn of \mathgrouo (or \def)  I wouldn't expect any such commands, which are used to define latex internals, being mentioned in any tutorial.

Comment: `copy - paste` I made some research.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`\i` is a standard latex command for dotless i, you should not redefine it.

This is why `\latex` has a `\newcommand` command, and you should not use `\def` except in internal package command where efficiency is more important. `\newcomand` would have given an error that it was redefining an existing command.

It seems that you want an upright i so

```
\newcommand\imagi{\mathrm{i}}
```

then use `\imgi`  (or use any other free name of your choice)

Answer (score 5):

Here's a suggestion which may, at first, seem a bit complicated; however, in the longer run it will almost certainly save you a lot of time and effort: Load the `siunitx` package and make a habit of encasing numbers -- real, imaginary, and complex -- in `\num{...}` wrappers. The `\num` macro works in both text and math mode.

The `siunitx` package lets you customize the appearance of the symbol for the imaginary unit; in the example below, I've selected

```
\sisetup{output-complex-root = \mathbf{i}}
```

to use a bold upright "**i**" as the symbol; the default is an ordinary (non-bold) upright "i".

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{output-complex-root = \mathbf{i}} % just for this example

\begin{document}
\num{2.71}, \num{-i}, \num{0.717\pm0.717i}

$\num{2.71}$, $\num{-i}$, $\num{0.717\pm0.717i}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 Yep. This also has a bunch of other advantages, like `\num{0.123456i}` will display with a thin space (`\,`) between the 3 and the 4, etc.